# How to count number of occurences in a list r

Tags: r, string, list, count

i have a list "list1" containing strings. i want to create a table with two columns : left column is the the string itslef, right column is the number of occurrences of that string in the list. it is important that no rows are duplicted, that is if e.g. "ABCD" appears 3 times in the list, i only want one row with the values "ABCD" and "3" and not 3 such rows. how can i do that ?

thanks

Answer (score 7):

If your vector is something like

```r
vec <- c("aaa","aaa","aab")
```

then `table` by itself gives you the counts (with the string as the names of the return):

```r
table(vec)
# vec
# aaa aab 
#   2   1
```

When we pass that to `as.data.frame`, this function will take the names and make one column, and then take the values and make a new column.

```r
as.data.frame(table(vec))
#   vec Freq
# 1 aaa    2
# 2 aab    1
```

---

If you truly meant a `list`, then:

```r
list1 <- as.list(vec)
list1
# [[1]]
# [1] "aaa"
# [[2]]
# [1] "aaa"
# [[3]]
# [1] "aab"
as.data.frame(table(unlist(list1)))
#   Var1 Freq
# 1  aaa    2
# 2  aab    1
```

Comment: hmm thank you for your comment, but i Have a list and not a vactor. does that work with lists too?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `stack` + `table` like below

```
> rev(stack(table(vec)))
  ind values
1 aaa      2
2 aab      1
```